# Browsers Don't Display "Cruftless" links (no index.html for local web dev.)

Tags: html, web, localhost, hyperlink, development-environment

Found an interesting article about "Cruftless" links (removing the "index.html" from links) but when I do that no browser shows the local pages.

http://www.nimblehost.com/blog/2012/11/why-cruftless-links-are-better/,

This is understandable, it's a 'file' url from a local machine, so what do people do to work on basic html sites offline?  How do they preview them?

For example, no browser (understandably) will display this...

file:///JOBS/ABC/About/

... but this is fine...

file:///JOBS/ABC/About/index.html

?... so what do people do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `file:` URLs is, by definition, system-dependent. Normally browsers map them to files in the file system in a relatively straightforward manner.

Thus, a link with `href` value like `file:///JOBS/ABC/About/` may or may not work, depending on system. It may fail, or it may open a generated document containing a directory (folder) listing, or it might do something else.

There is normally no need to get around this, and it is pointless to worry about SEO when dealing with local files.

This could, however, matter during site development when you work with a site locally (and perhaps test and demonstrate it locally). Then you might wish to have, say, `<a href="About/">About us</a>` so that it works locally as well as on a server, yielding `About/index.html` in both cases but without hard-wiring `index.html` in HTML markup.

I’m afraid the answer is “you can’t”. But as a workaound, you can install and use a local HTTP server, with settings similar to those that you will have on the real server. This means a little extra work (mainly downloading and installing and configuring software like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)), but it also gives you important other benefits, like testing your pages locally with server-based features (to the extent that the real server is similar to the local server).

Comment: Thank you. So I have to use a local server.